# Example of undefined behaviour involving the use of const_cast

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

For illustrative purposes, I have been trying to find an example, by using gcc, where the output of a program is different with and without optimization enabled (with and without `-O3`). The purpose of finding such example is to show how optimizations could make an apparently correct program behave different after optimizations have been active if the code contains undefined behaviour.

I have been trying different "combos" of the following program:

```
// I have tried defining blind in this and in a separate module. The result is the same.
void blind(int const* p) { ++*const_cast<int*>(p); }

#include <iostream>

int constant() { return 0; }

int main()
{
    int const p = constant();
    blind(&p);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

I was expecting that, without optimizations enabled, this program will show 1, but with optimizations enabled (`-O3`) it will show 0 (by replacing `std::cout << p` by `std::cout << 0` directly), but that's not the case. If I replace the initialization by `int const p = 0`, it will print `0` with and without optimizations enabled, and so the behaviour is again the same.

I have tried different alternatives like doing arithmetic operations (expecting the compiler to prefer to "pre-compute" the value or something), calling `blind` several times, etc. But nothing works.

- I would like to find a variation of the program above whose behaviour change when activating optimizations.
- Or... another different example that could help to illustrate that optimizations can change the observable behaviour of a program if such program contains undefined behaviour.

*NOTE:* Preferably, one example where the program won't probably crash in the optimized version.

Comment: If the code has undefined behavior... then it doesn't matter if optimizations change the behavior. You have in incorrect program either way. The fact that a C++ program compiles doesn't mean it is a correct program, even though it might seem to give the expected output. So even if you obeserve a difference... what does it matter?

Comment: @PepijnKramer UB In C++ is sort of a joke. Even "x=x+1" can result in undefined behavior. I'd say pretty much every line of every code may potentially contain UB.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher I am not going to take that bait

Comment: If you want examples of the optimizer interacting with undefined behavior, I would point you to [the LLVM Project (3-part) blog post "What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior"](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). If you want an example using `const_cast` specifically, well... it might not exist. `const_cast` has to do with aliasing, and aliasing prevents a lot of optimizations, so I would be surprised to see a `const_cast`-UB lead to any optimization.

Comment: `const_cast` applied to an object that wasn't `const` in the first place is not UB.

Comment: @MarkRansom `p` was defined as `const` and thus `p` is a constant object, right?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Instead of accusing me of using malice and ill intent, you could alternatively have engaged in a productive conversation. Very sad you elected to take the easy route.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher I did not suspect malice...  just a long tedious discussion and I didn't feel like having one. When UB triggers is well defined/documented (even the x=x+1 signed/unsigned mess). And I want to leave it like that. Apologies if you feel wronged by my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice and very simple case that matches the kind of example I was looking for is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

bool check(int i)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    return j < i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << check(INT_MAX) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Without optimizations enabled, `check` returns `1`, because overflow did happen. With optimizations enabled, even with `-O1`, `check` returns `0`.

I started with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

bool check(int i)
{
    return i + 1 < i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << check(INT_MAX) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since signed integer overflow is UB, the compiler directly returned `0` without performing the actual comparision even without optimizations enabled:
[image]

Since the behaviour was still the same with and without optimizations, I decided to move the calculation of `i + 1` to a new variable `j`:

```
bool check(int i)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    return j < i;
}
```

Now, the compiler, in a non-optimized build, is forced to actually calculate `j` so the variable can be inspected with a debugger, and the comparision is actually performed, and that's why it returns `1`.

However, with `-O1`, the compiler translated `check` to its equivalent form `return i + 1 < i`, which becomes `return 0` as in the previous variation of the program.

Comment: `gcc -fwrapv` makes signed integer overflow well-defined as wrapping.  The GCC default is `-fno-wrapv`, since ISO C says it's UB.  And yes, the key thing is that with optimization enabled, compilers can optimize across statements for non-`const` variables, otherwise they can't/don't.  ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394))

Answer (score 2):

Now may be my time to shine. [I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616199/why-is-my-compiler-optimizing-this-for-loop-into-an-infinite-loop-when-compile) a while ago and it seems to perfectly demonstrate an example of what you are looking for in a very short/simple program, which I will include below for completeness:

```
#include <iostream>

int broken_for_loop(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i+= 1000){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    broken_for_loop();
}
```

You can see the discussion/explanation there (long story short, I don't return from a function that should return an int), but I think it does a good job of demonstrating how some UB can be pretty sneaky in presenting itself only in optimized binaries if you're not thinking about it/paying attention to compiler warnings.

Adding in case it wasnt clear:
When compiled without optimization, the program prints 0...9000 and then exits properly. When compiled with `-O3` the loop runs forever.

Compiled with: `g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`

Comment: Where's the `const_cast`?

Comment: @BenVoigt There isnt one, the question asked for a modification to the original example "Or... another different example that could help to illustrate that optimizations can change the observable behaviour of a program if such program contains undefined behaviour."

Comment: @DouglasB: Ahh, I interpreted the question based on the assumption that the topic is "undefined behavior involving the use of `const_cast`", per the title

Answer (score 1):

When the initializer for a `const int` is a constant expression (like `0`), the language rules say it becomes `constexpr` (thanks @Artyer for pointing this out).  So there is a difference in the C++ semantics for `const int p = 0;` vs. `const int p = foo();` unless you declare `constexpr int foo(){...}`, which is probably why compilers optimize them differently in practice.

---

When the definition of `blind()` isn't visible to the optimizer, I think this is still a missed optimization by GCC (and clang, ICC, and MSVC).  They *could* choose to assume that nothing can modify a `const` the same way it does assume nothing modifies a `constexpr`, because a program that does has undefined behaviour.

When `blind()` is in the same compilation unit without `__attribute__((noinline,noipa))`, the UB is visible at compile time if optimization is enabled, so all bets are off and no amount of weirdness is particularly surprising.

But with just a prototype for `blind()`, compilers have to make asm that would work for a `blind()` that didn't have undefined behaviour, so it's interesting to look at what assumptions/optimizations they did make.  And to consider whether they'd be allowed to compile the way you expected.

---

With  `const int p = 0;`, GCC and clang  propagate that constant to later uses of `p` in the same function (even with optimization disabled), correctly assuming that nothing else can possibly have changed the value of a `const` object.  (Not even a debugger, which is something gcc and clang's `-O0` default code gen is designed to support for non-const variables; that's one reason why they make [separate blocks of asm for each statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) which don't keep anything in registers across statements.)

I think it's a missed optimization to not constant-propagate `const int p = constant();` in the same case, after inlining `constant()` to a constant `0`.  It's still a `const int` object so it's still UB for anything else to modify it.

Of course that doesn't happen in a debug build; without inlining `constant()` they don't know at compile-time what the actual value will be, so they can't use it as an immediate operand for later instructions.  So compilers load it from memory at `p`'s usual address, the same one they passed to `blind()`.  So they use the modified value in debug builds, that's expected.

In optimized builds, they don't `call constant`, they store an immediate `0` to initialize the stack space whose address they pass to `blind()`, like we'd expect.  **But then after the call, they reload it instead of using another immediate `0`.**  This is the missed optimization.

For a large object, it could be more efficient to use the copy that exists in memory instead of generating it again, especially if passing it to a print function passed by reference.  But that's not the case for `int`; it *is* more efficient to just zero a register as an arg passed by value for `std::cout::operator<<( int )` than to reload from the stack.

---

#### `constexpr` changes behaviour (for both debug and optimized)

With `constexpr int constant(){ return 0; }`, GCC and clang treat `const int p = constant();` exactly the same as `const int p = 0;`, because `constant()` is a constant expression just like `0`.  It gets inlined even with `gcc -O0`, and the constant `0` gets used after the call to `blind()`, not reloading `p`.

Still not an example of code that changes at `-O0` vs. `-O3`, though.

---

Apparently it matters to the compiler internals that it was initialized with a "constant expression", whether that's a literal or a `constexpr` function return value.  But that's not fundamental, it's still UB to modify a `const int` no matter how it was initialized.

I'm not sure if compilers are intentionally avoiding this optimization or if it' just a quirk.  Maybe not *intentionally* for this case, but as collateral damage of avoiding some class of things for some reason?

Or perhaps just because for constant-propagation purposes, it's not known until after inlining `constant()` that `const int p` will have a value that's known at compile time.  But with `constexpr int constant()`, the compiler can treat the function call as part of a constant expression, so it definitely can assume it will have a known value for all later uses of `p`.  This explanation seems overly simplistic because normally constant-propagation does work even for things that aren't `constexpr`, and GCC/clang transform program logic into [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) as part of compilation, doing most of the optimization work on that, which should make it easy to see if a value is modified or not.

Maybe when considering passing the address to a function, they don't consider that the underlying object is known to be `const`, only whether it was initialized with a `constexpr`.  If the object in question was only passed or returned by reference to this function, like `const int *pptr = foo();` and `blind(pptr)`, the underlying object might not be `const`, in which case `blind()` could modify `*pptr` without UB.

I find it surprising that both GCC and clang miss this optimization, but I'm pretty confident that it is actually undefined behaviour for `blind()` to modify the pointed-to `const int`, even when it's in automatic storage. (Not static where it could actually be in a read-only page and crash in practice.)

I even checked MSVC and ICC 2021 (classic, not LLVM-based), and they're the same as GCC/clang, not constant-propagating across `blind()` unless you use a constant expression to init `p`, making it a `constexpr`.    (GCC/clang targeting other ISAs are of course the same; this optimization decision happens in the target-independent middle-end.)

I guess they all just base their optimization choice on whether or not its `constexpr`, even though though all 4 of those compilers were independently developed.

---

**To make the asm simpler to look at on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHAD06wDUDKh4CUxbJgDMACI7qFvBBNEAtAnEqKvoy2JbhmIAnikKJhoAgpsAPpApgEAjEPARLw3EFQXbBWhTUgIg5zOZbLabLaYACOXjwADcxIwCFsiFsEjDHEYrgx3lslAdiGDMFs0CwEnQwWktl4GIQ/oD1oS9ugthEkQx0BBruyBOMAFSUjEmADsFiOlmsirQDHGQNE4xObmuipO2AgCTmJ016tOQux/GI7IMRlIW20XnGW2ARLZhAZD1QRAInwSmCForw4slwRlcr1SpVtqFjvW5mOwWQ3iwR2OpuSEMwrAt6aTN1UD0x2IICDwCi2AHc6LRfZgyQBxNxucmXRFTd7SraoBKOFh4ABeAbJTCbTE%2BHsM4uLYKuZLrbIUrDZTEbCROpw0dJzXnwtPQe1pFcMZODB2APIEQsTCpqgggqo1W2IHeW9I0W0jjVB0ARfQQthYJhgk/NMNSFTEa22Fs6yWMlR3HKcnwYD0bwg%2B8mEfdorkbARaE%2BSlkhSSUAyodd2UMRlMF3eV9XfMlMCrX8FBSARm0IBA0LpKVgmABDEOxaEyQUZYHgbUTyI9bte2QQTkkwRtdg3S5L1Y8Zb3uR4H2wrYqEeFhKUPPCCE/HFCUYfi6xHMc8AnScTMYJgaPQD16HBUSJSlGUMVUwxgDZTctmJbw2VQOjDgrOkCAAOnEpC%2BQYegeL09jbIbHLOIeNKsXWV82MpfNzkA44rABRCkpyirDxy29YJq4q42lCBzAANmtVMAWxRDxnQEAUCEk0TSagsprADgTAAVjcBg5qA7FVqWlaOBIyCvFUxlXISegXTrRjXFoYrRQMRx6AalIGAAa0qyyavSvECWi0k%2B0pSFBACqS7IclgSC3Q76GK38CH/LZqrtMCQI4BZaE4BbeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrEZJYVjZTMeFIAhNERhYHpAMwAE5kq4HqmeZlmmbVfROEkNGKaxzheAUEANDJimFjgWAkA5LljvIShJbofpgC4Y5miwQk8FWAA1PBMCbAB5CN0dJmhaBuYgBYgCIeYiYJak%2BThSet5hiE%2BXWIm0Cpye4XgOTYQRdcyu2Md4LBoWANwxFoAWvdILAoKMcQg5jvBf0qeyo8xziKhhNZSeuVoeaRCIWWdjwsB5iFXPtxG%2BAMYAFC1nX9cYKuZEEEQSQkaR%2BEERQVHURPdGaN1jDxyx9ChAXIAWDC0ij25deOXhUHs4hISwSfPxaNo0hcaURiaUhAimIoSmyZJUgEfez9yNIehP/oxlaD2qgmK/H%2B3gROjqO%2B%2BhiMZX88I0PQ%2Blv7H1/hIBYChCarAgRzDgqMUQ82xttVQsQeq3B6pIX0yBkBbCVgzLYEBcCEBIFqZWcxeCey0OiUgCASxYBiJvamZgNDJViMcDhnCuEcOkMjDgXNEGJ2QfzQWwsg6ixgIgcanJ5ZkAoBAOWx0QCK2VjHTAatNbaz1gbFuxtTbm0tonR2tsW7GOdq7d2DgW4%2B1JP7ciPMQ5eDDhHKOpNY5hQTpjfAKdHBpx5pnZA2cW55z4ZjQuxdPilzWJjCuLAq4LCoLXeuWim6G14N3YQohxBSFbvIJQagea6DMPoMKKBR42ELhvaeLkFR8yxivNeGl4CQKfpUZwEBXBv0PtKH%2BMw/6JHPu0LpOQL4MF6afd%2Bz9P4AMyAfcobSOgTHGQ/QYXQukgMmIUcBXBIHQPYDsuBCD0aY2QVsVB6DMHYNwfgrghDiFEBdCTChYjqFUxppIZKtMvnfJ%2BT8nqcCBHHKXnUgWQsqHVzFlIxR0QZYKNQDIpROYwqMw0ELVW6tMAN20c3aOejogGKtjbZ2piiUuzdh7ax8LfYEDsYHLxmBQ7h1oJHFu7j47RODsnZ%2BfjE4BKCdHEJBcoQRKieXSEcSvYJKSVi1JujZDt2yV3WQvcCkDxAMcEpRgynajHpU5pWMan6k4PPRe9ToiNKqVvKZfgOl70AaMbp6Bln9JGUM%2B1B9XW3zAX04BrT2hf3qO631H9FldGdcAmZQD/5hu9RM3ZywYEHL4UcpBnAzloIwVgpFtJGbJVYceIh%2BAHlkJ2ZQkWbyzALQBdzIRILRHgpoXwswNaTl1IbQsFevE/CSCAA%3D%3D%3D)**, I changed `cout<<p` to `volatile int sink = p;` to see whether gcc/clang would `mov dword ptr [rsp+4], 0` a constant zero, or would load+store to copy from `p`'s address to `sink`.  `cout << p << '\n'` was simpler, but still messy vs. that.

Seeing constant vs. load+store is the behaviour we're ultimately interested in, so I'd rather see that directly than see a 0 or 1 and have to think through the steps to which I was expecting in which case.  You can mouseover the `volatile int sink = p;` line and it'll highlight the corresponding instruction(s) in the asm output panes.

I could have just done `return p`, especially from a function not called `main` so it's not special.  In fact that's even easier, makes [even simpler asm](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGE6a4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZmakAA6oCoRODB7evv5JKWkCwaERLNGx8baY9o4CQgRMxASZPn5SFVXptfUEheFRMXEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwcAPRrANQMqHiJTJsmAMwAItuomyEEMQC0icSoK%2BhLYpuGYgCeqQomGgCCGwA%2BoCmAQCMQ8JEvNdgVAdiFaCFMKR4ftZrNNpsNptMABHLx4ABuYkYBE2RE2iWhjiMlwYb02Sn2xFBmE2aBYiTooPSmy8DEIvwBa0Ju3Qm0iiIY6AgV3ZAiGACpKRiTAB2CyHSzWRVoBhDQGiIbHNxXRXHbAQRKzY6a9UnIXY/jEdkGIykTbaLxDTbAIlswgM%2B6oIgED6JTBC0V4cWSkIyuV6pUq21Cx1rcxHELIbxYQ5HU0pcGYVgW9NJ66qe6Y7EEBB4BSbADudFovswZIA4m43OSLgikW9pZtUIlHCw8AAvANkphNpgfD2GcXF0GXMl1tkKVhspiNxLHE4aOk5rz4WnoXa0iuGMnB/bAHkCIWJhV1QQQVUazbEDtLekaLahxqg6/wvoImz8Kgn5phqQqYjWWwtnWixkqO45Tk%2BDAejeEH3kwj7VPSDYjgwtAfJSKSpJKAZUOu7KGIymC7vK%2BrvmSmBVr%2BCipAIzaEAgqF0lKITAPBCHYlCZIKEs9wNqJ5Eet2vbIIJKSYI2Owbhcl6sRMgh3A8D5YZBDwsJSh64QQn44oSjD8XWI5jngE6TiZjBMDR6AevQYKiRKUoyhiqmGMAbKbpsxLeGyqB0QcFZ0gQAB04mIXyZEaY2Vk2SRFacfcqVYmsr5sZS%2BZnIBRxWP8CGJXpd7lfVt4wVVhVxtKEDmAAbNaqb/NiCFDOgIAoEJJommV40FpsYAcCYACsbgMLNQHYiti3LRwlyNiwXiqYyLmJPQLp1oxri0IVGyigYjj0HVqQMAA1o1B5VWleIElFpJ9pSEKCP5Um2fZLAkFuh30Jday/gQ/6bJVdo1Qh0Ow691V/PaHDzLQnDzbwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYjKLMsbKZjwpAEJomPzI9cQABxJUcHOc1znPSNjHCSHjDNE5wvAKCAGh0wz8xwLASAclyx3kJQ8t0P0wBcEcXCkFghJ4CsABqeCYE2ADyEb47TNC0NcxBixAkRC5EIT1B8nC007zDEB8JuRNomAOG7vAcmwggm2RrsE7wWBQsAbhiLQYvcFHmAsKF4iR9reC/g4/qJ4TnH%2B9Cqy01clRC4ikQsl7HhYEL4IuYH8xUAYwAKIbxtm4wgcyIIIgkjk/CCIoKjqBnuha26xhk5Y%2BiQmLkDzOh6SJzcJtHJsNwAOrxxvm87Dc/Lepg6A3MSEKefQvCoHZxAQlg8%2Bfm0/tES40qjC0pBBEi0z9FrySpERd%2Beh/75AYFMPosQtZ2Gfh0YYjRPDND0NAnONQ4HgJKL/WwcCgFQLQd/CBEh5gKEpisQh%2BgcaCwzsTLaqgWZdRuF1SQvpkDIE2BrJKXBNgQFwIQEgWpNazF4PTSO6JSAIBLFgWIj9mZmC4ElLqCjFFKMUWqch/NKGE2oaLcWksRGkBlogUanJVZkAoBAFWx0QDq01trTAusDZG1NubbuVsbZ2wdhnD2Ltu5eK9j7P2Ack6kGDqSMO5EhbRy8LHeOidaZYFTkYdOhN8DZ0cHZPOvAC7ICLt3UufNCYVyrh8GuqxCb1xYI3PgLc26OM7hbXgg9hCiHEK0Rpw81BC10AkSeKBp42Arg/RezkFScFXpom%2Bd8NLwCIZUGBzgICuBwZ/aU6CZh/zyIAhBYxcgAPSKszByCiKdBGFsj%2BhzYGTHwRgyBWCuhLImA0fZkCiEkPYFwLGFCURC2oZsWh9DGHMNYewzh3D8BEBdDTQRuitCiJkfNNRAsvlUJFrYHRwiYX6JgIYixMQlbmNQMYyxOZQpcC6hoCWOs9aYHbk4ruQTXExHcY7Z2XsfEsu9r7Z%2B3cQmh3DhEzAMc460ATt3eJadSlRyzjA9JQssk5KCXk8ukIiklLrhCCpScm7VJpXUlxsg%2B4tOkG0pQHSx4gCOPoUKvTtQzwGdMomwz9SjLXrvHeW996HyUCfM%2BeAL6YCvhMmMUyF5PxQX4BZb9Tl6C/kUAh6zdkCCWSAoiTykGzLDcc%2BBWQznpqOXg2N1ykHYKjbgy5Ba1kvKWKQ95ajcZIs0ZwX5dCGFMOJbSUlSUNCdq4Tw8F/D3lCKlkzOI8K%2BaIvxg2jg2iJbosZmoswGir4otnaIm%2BvE/CSCAA%3D%3D) (but load vs. zero instead of 2 instructions vs. 1).  Still, it avoids the fact that GCC implicitly treats `main` as `__attribute__((cold))`, on the assumption that real programs don't spend most of their time in `main`.  But the missed optimization is still present in `int foo()`.

If you wanted to look at the case where UB is visible at compile time (which I didn't), you could see if it was storing a constant `1` when `blind()` was inlined.  I expect so.

Comment: `const int p = 0` and `const int p = constant()` (where `constant` is not a `constexpr` function) have different behaviour because `p` has an integral type, `const int p = 0;` is the same as `constexpr int p = 0`, so `std::operator<<(std::cout, p)` doesn't odr use `p` (it just creates a new constant value, `operator<<` takes int by value), but if `p` isn't constant initialized it does. That's why you don't see a difference between -O0 and -O3 with `const int p = 0`, GCC doesn't actually optimize any const accesses here. See: https://godbolt.org/z/saE34fcdv

Answer (score 0):

Several cases show different behavior from debug to non-debug/optimized code. Undefined behavior is not the only reason why this would happen as it is implied in some of the answers and comments.

1. It will run slower. If the result depends on how long the code runs, like in an optimization, the results will be systematically different.

This happens a lot with FPGA "compiling" since the placement/routing phase is essentially just an optimization loop.

Example: let's compute log(2) using my own weird version of an alternating harmonic series. I stop the series after a given time elapsed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>

double calcln2() {
    constexpr size_t N = 1000000;
    std::array<double,N> values;
    for ( double& x : values ) x = 0;
    uint64_t t0 = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
    for  ( size_t j=1; __builtin_ia32_rdtsc() - t0 < 10000000ULL; j++ ) {
        for ( double& x : values ) { 
            if ( j%2==0 ) {
                x -= 1/double(j);
            } else {
                x += 1/double(j);
            }
        }
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for ( double& x : values ) sum += x;
    return sum/N;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << log(2) - calcln2() << std::endl;
}
```

The `main()` function will basically output the calculation error. An example of a debug run would give me 0.193147 while on a release run would result in 0.0399365, much less.

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zMc5dPns6

I can think of other cases but I will not go in the depth of generating an example code for each.

2. Optimizations will typically imply fast math which might make rounding issues worse. On the other hand, optimizations might collapse an entire series (say the alternating harmonic series above) in its closed formula in which case it will be more precise.
3. Executable size will be larger which can have side effects if
4. Asserts will only trigger in debug mode so it will crash in one and not in another

Comment: *Optimizations will typically imply fast math* - Compilers other than ICC do *not* enable `-ffast-math` as part of `-O3`.  You still get strict FP semantics unless you use `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math`.  Also, `gcc -O3` alone doesn't define `NDEBUG`, so `assert()` is still active.